# Calculations on several dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes. Below is an example of each of them.

```
        df_min
scale   code    R1  R2 ...  
  1      121    50  30
  2      121    35  45
  3      121    40  50
  4      121    20  30
  5      121    20  35
  1      313    10   7
  2      313    13  10
  3      313    10  12
  4      313    15  8
  5      313    17  10
...

        df_rate
scale   code    R1  R2 ...
  1      121    20  40
  2      121    30  20
  3      121    20  30
  4      121    15  40
  5      121    10  30
  1      313    10   5
  2      313    15  10
  3      313    25  10
  4      313    10  15
  5      313    20   5
...

        df_max
scale   code    R1  R2 ...
  1      121    30  200
  2      121    100 175
  3      121    70  100
  4      121    80  90
  5      121    75  35
  1      313    60  70
  2      313    35  70
  3      313    50  60
  4      313    50  45
  5      313    45  68
...

     df_stock
code    R1  R2 ...
 121    100 150
 313    70  65
....

        df_new
scale   code     R1  R2 ...
  1      121    NaN NaN
  2      121    NaN NaN
  3      121    NaN NaN
  4      121    NaN NaN
  5      121    NaN NaN
  1      313    NaN NaN
  2      313    NaN NaN
  3      313    NaN NaN
  4      313    NaN NaN
  5      313    NaN NaN
...
```

Columns like `R1` and `R2` are cities and there can be many. The `code` column has unique product codes. They can also be many. The `scale` marks the number of the week for which I am making calculations. For each `code`, it's five weeks. Also I have an empty dataframe, in which I need to record the results of calculations.

I will give an example of a specific calculation, I hope it will be clearer. In an empty dataframe I take a cell where the `scale` is `1` and the `code` is `121` and columnn `R1`. I find the corresponding value in `df_stock`. It is equal to `100`. from it I subtract the value from `df_rate` from the column `R1`, where the `scale` is `1`. If this value is greater than the value from `df_min` from the column `R1`, where the `scale` is `1`, I write it down, if less, then I take the value from `df_max` from column `R1`, where the `scale` is `1`. It turned out `80`, it is more than `50`, so I write it down. For the next cell, I subtract from the calculated value(`80`) next value in the column `R1`, where the `scale` is `2`. And I also check it. It turned out `50`. I write it down. And so on. From the table `df_stock` I take the first value, from which I begin to subtract.

In fact, `df_min` is the minimum value and if I go below it, then I need to copy the corresponding value from `df_max`.

These calculations must be made for each unique `code` (each `code` is represented in the `scale` range from `1` to `5`) and for each column like `R1` and `R2`.

The result of the example is as follows:

```
scale   code    R1  R2 ...
  1      121    80  110
  2      121    50  90
  3      121    70  60
  4      121    55  90
  5      121    45  60
  1      313    60  60
  2      313    45  50
  3      313    20  40
  4      313    50  25
  5      313    30  20
...
```

I will be very grateful for any help!

**UPD**  I wrote a script that does what I need. It is not optimal, but I have no other ideas. Is it possible to change it and add to it a loop? In my original data `scale` is between `1` and `26` and with my code I have to write a condition for each value from the `scale`.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
b = (121,121,121,121,121,313,313,313,313,313,444,444,444,444,444)

columns = ['scale', 'code', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3']
index = np.arange(15)

df_min = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)
df_min['scale'] = a
df_min['code'] = b
df_min['R1'] = np.random.randint(10, 50, size=15)
df_min['R2'] = np.random.randint(10, 50, size=15)
df_min['R3'] = np.random.randint(10, 50, size=15)

df_rate = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)
df_rate['scale'] = a
df_rate['code'] = b
df_rate['R1'] = np.random.randint(5, 40, size=15)
df_rate['R2'] = np.random.randint(5, 40, size=15)
df_rate['R3'] = np.random.randint(5, 40, size=15)

df_max = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)
df_max['scale'] = a
df_max['code'] = b
df_max['R1'] = np.random.randint(50, 150, size=15)
df_max['R2'] = np.random.randint(50, 150, size=15)
df_max['R3'] = np.random.randint(50, 150, size=15)

index1 = np.arange(3)
df_stock = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index1)
df_stock['code'] = (121,313,444)
df_stock['R1'] = np.random.randint(100, 300, size=3)
df_stock['R2'] = np.random.randint(100, 300, size=3)
df_stock['R3'] = np.random.randint(100, 300, size=3)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)
df_new['scale'] = a
df_new['code'] = b

# set the index to 'code' to subtract df_rate from df_stock
df_stock = df_stock.set_index('code')
df_rate = df_rate.set_index('code')
df_new = df_stock - df_rate
# have to add back in the 'scale' column since it wasn't present in df_rate
df_new['scale'] = df_rate['scale']
# now set the index to use both 'code' and 'scale'
df_new = df_new.reset_index()
df_new = df_new.set_index(['code', 'scale'])
df_min = df_min.set_index(['code', 'scale'])
df_max = df_max.set_index(['code', 'scale'])
df_new = df_new.mask(df_new < df_min, df_max)

df_min = df_min.reset_index()
df_min.insert(2, 'test', 0)
df_max = df_max.reset_index()
df_max.insert(2, 'test', 0)
df_new = df_new.reset_index()
df_new.insert(2, 'test', 0)
df_rate = df_rate.reset_index()
df_rate.insert(2, 'test', 0)

df_new.loc[df_new['scale'].between(2,5), 'test':] = np.nan

df_rate_p = df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 2, :'scale']
df_new.index +=1
df_rate_p1 = df_new.loc[df_new['scale'] == 1, 'test':] - df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 2, 'test':]
df_new2 = pd.concat([df_rate_p, df_rate_p1], axis=1)
df_new = df_new.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df_new2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()
df_new = df_new.mask(df_new < df_min, df_max)

df_rate_p = df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 3, :'scale']
df_new.index +=1
df_rate_p1 = df_new.loc[df_new['scale'] == 2, 'test':] - df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 3, 'test':]
df_new2 = pd.concat([df_rate_p, df_rate_p1], axis=1)
df_new = df_new.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df_new2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()
df_new = df_new.mask(df_new < df_min, df_max)

df_rate_p = df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 4, :'scale']
df_new.index +=1
df_rate_p1 = df_new.loc[df_new['scale'] == 3, 'test':] - df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 4, 'test':]
df_new2 = pd.concat([df_rate_p, df_rate_p1], axis=1)
df_new = df_new.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df_new2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()
df_new = df_new.mask(df_new < df_min, df_max)

df_rate_p = df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 5, :'scale']
df_new.index +=1
df_rate_p1 = df_new.loc[df_new['scale'] == 4, 'test':] - df_rate.loc[df_rate['scale'] == 5, 'test':]
df_new2 = pd.concat([df_rate_p, df_rate_p1], axis=1)
df_new = df_new.set_index(['code', 'scale']).fillna(df_new2.set_index(['code', 'scale'])).reset_index()
df_new = df_new.mask(df_new < df_min, df_max)
df_new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pandas `index` and `MultiIndex` is very useful for comparing the correct rows with eachother.

Here is how you would use it:

```
# set the index to 'code' to subtract df_rate from df_stock
df_stock = df_stock.set_index('code')
df_rate = df_rate.set_index('code')
df_new = df_stock - df_rate
# have to add back in the 'scale' column since it wasn't present in df_rate
df_new['scale'] = df_rate['scale']

# now set the index to use both 'code' and 'scale'
df_new = df_new.reset_index()
df_new = df_new.set_index(['code', 'scale'])
df_min = df_min.set_index(['code', 'scale'])
df_max = df_max.set_index(['code', 'scale'])

# you may not actually need these lines, but sometimes it is necessary!
# intersection = df_new.index.intersection(df_min.index).intersection(df_max.index)
# df_new = df_new.loc[intersection]
# df_min = df_min.loc[intersection]
# df_max = df_max.loc[intersection]

# if df_new < df_max, then use values from df_max
# I didn't actually understand what you meant to do with the
# the data, so this is probably not quite what you intended,
# but you can can use this to see how it works and implement
# your algorithm
df_new = df_new.mask(df_new < df_min, df_max)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really helped me move on in my work.